# React--Button onclick event not working in Component

Tags: reactjs

I have written a component with two buttons and an on click event for them, that should show an alert message .I am not getting any error in the code ,but when i click the button nothing happens .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

     class Vehicle extends Component{
       remove(){
        alert("Remove button clicked");
    }
    submit(){
        alert("Submit button clicked");
    }

        render()
        {

             return(<div>
                 <h1>Select your Vehicle</h1>
                 <input type='submit' onclick={this.submit} value="Click Me"></input>
                 <button type="button" onclick={this.remove}>Reset</button>
                 </div>
            );
    }

    }
    export default Vehicle;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The onclick method is wrong .Is not onclick its onClick...

Try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

     class Vehicle extends Component{
       remove(){
        alert("Remove button clicked");
    }
    submit(){
        alert("Submit button clicked");
    }

        render()
        {

             return(<div>
                 <h1>Select your Vehicle</h1>
                 <input type='submit' onClick={this.submit} value="Click Me"></input>
                 <button type="button" onClick={this.remove}>Reset</button>
                 </div>
            );
    }

    }
    export default Vehicle;
```

Running Code is here.Please do check
https://codesandbox.io/s/xzxqyqn58z

Answer (score 2):

Handling events with React elements is very similar to handling events on DOM elements. There are some syntactic differences:

- React events are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase.
- With JSX you pass a function as the event handler, rather than a string.

Rename your `onclick` event to camelCase and it should work

```
render()
    {

         return(<div>
             <h1>Select your Vehicle</h1>
             <input type='submit' onClick={this.submit} value="Click Me"></input>
             <button type="button" onClick={this.remove}>Reset</button>
             </div>
        );
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
class Vehicle extends React.Component{
       remove(){
        alert("Remove button clicked");
    }
    submit(){
        alert("Submit button clicked");
    }

        render()
        {

             return(<div>
                 <h1>Select your Vehicle</h1>
                 <input type='submit' onClick={this.submit} value="Click Me"></input>
                 <button type="button" onClick={this.remove}>Reset</button>
                 </div>
            );
    }

    }
    
ReactDOM.render(<Vehicle/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```